# Index out of range when delete last cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I tried to delete cell in a TableView, everything runs fine until I delete the last cell, and I got an error: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range".

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard editingStyle == .delete else {return}
    classList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    let subject = classList[indexPath.row]
    PersistenceService.context.delete(subject)
    PersistenceService.saveContext()

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Class> = Class.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let classList = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.classList = classList
    } catch {}
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    print("Delete \(subject)")
}
```

Then i tried to let subject = classList[indexPath.row-1], which will solve the error of deleting the last cell, but it causes another error is when I try to delete the first cell of the TableView. Please help me to fix this bug, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After removing the object from `classList` the number of items changes so later `classList[indexPath.row]` crashes because the index doesn't exist anymore.

You have to change the order

```
let subject = classList[indexPath.row]
classList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
PersistenceService.context.delete(subject)
PersistenceService.saveContext()
```

and delete this code:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Class> = Class.fetchRequest()
do {
    let classList = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    self.classList = classList
} catch {}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

It's pointless, you don't need to refetch the data.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you remove an item from `classList` and then try to access it.

```
classList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
...
let subject = classList[indexPath.row]
```

move `let subject = classList[indexPath.row]` above the code where you remove the row